# MS CRM Source of plug-in event

Tags: dynamics-crm

I have written a plug-in and would like to know if it was fired by ,  the web service api, Import data, web form or outlook client.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look at the IPluginExecutionContext.CallerOrigin property (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc156395.aspx). You can determine if it was from the application, async service, API, or if the plugin is being replayed after coming from offline.